# Not reloading the right data in UITabeView

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, xcode4.6

I wrote this code to reload the UItableView with an events that has the same date as the current date when the user click on todays events UIButton in the main view controller but the problem is the below code is not reloading the right data (it just gives the initial data without comparing the date of the event with the date of the calendar in the IPhone), my data comes from a json file within the project and consists from NSArray of events, each has a different value for each key and one of these keys is the data of that event ("date"), can anyone plz clarify for me why the below code is not returning the right data ??

```
  @implementation MainViewController {
 NSArray *_events;
 }



.... 

- (IBAction)upcomingEvents:(id)sender {

NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];


for (Events *event in _events){

    if([event.date isEqualToString:dateString]){

       [self.myTableView reloadData];

    }

}


}
```

Comment: Well if `_events` is your datasource, then you just have to filter the array and then send a `reloadData` message to your tableview to refresh. Right now you're just refreshing your tableview without any changes in your datasource array.

Comment: @Alladinian and how to filter the array ?? (Im quiet new to Xcode and objective-C)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a UITableViewDataSource you should make sure that it returns only the events that match your condition `[event.date isEqualToString:dateString]`

You can do

```
NSArray * dateEvents = [_events filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(Events * event, NSDictionary *bindings)
{
    return [event.date isEqualToString:dateString];
}];
```

Then you can use `dateEvents` for your UITableViewDataSource.

Comment: yes Im using UITAbleViewDataSource and does this means that I don't have to use the for condition again ?? and where should I include the above declaration?? within the IBAction ?

Comment: You would want to update dateEvents in the 'upcomingEvents' method. And make sure that the UITableViewDataSource is using dateEvents instead of events. You will probably want to make dateEvents into a property on your class.

Comment: when I included your above code within my code I got an error in [_events] saying (UNKNOWN RECEIVER) even though I have declared that array (NSArray *_events) within my implementation part .. I don't understand !!! and how to include dateEvents in my UITableViewDataSource ? (Im quiet new To all this, i will appreciate any further clarification)

Comment: @user3066516, it's not clear why _events gives you that error, since you were using that in your last question, and it was working there. To use dateEvents instead of _events as your data source you just use it in the data source methods (numberOfRowsInSection, cellForRowAtIndexPath, etc.) instead of using _events. You might want to have an if-else clause to choose which array you use depending on a  flag that you set in the upcomingEvents method.

Comment: It might help to see some more of your code to understand what you need to change. Also, what exactly is the error you get? Unknown receiver means an unknown identifier. Are you sure _events is in scope where you're using it? Is it a compile time error or a runtime error?

Comment: @rdelmar apparently Im not getting any error now but still those IBAction are activated (they are not loading the data according to the date) the apps just start with all the events even though by default when the app starts, only todays events should be shown and when the user click on future events button, all the future events will be loaded .. how to do an if else clause depending on the flag I set ??     PS, u could check my next question to see my modified code for that part. Thanks